# How to upload image in CkEditor in ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ckeditor

I'm new to CkEditor, I've successfully integreted and customized the editor to my page but I can't upload images. In CkEditor documentation I found They using a PhP script to upload file but i'm not sure how can I add this to my ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: it's possible add php file to your ASP.NET MVC project, but there is not so much sense. Most common to upload files via HTTP POST request, so you need to create view in your project which will accept post with uploaded files. Next replace URL to this view for this CKEditor file upload plugin you using (Probably there should be configuration option) and you are done.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have managed to do it via POST request to Controller.

Comment: Please share your solution....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

follow my way step by step:

first of all, add this to your layout:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

then add this to your view:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>

        CKEDITOR.replace('textarea's name', {
            customConfig: '/js/CustomConfig.js'
        });

    </script>
}
```

you can see I'm using CDN and CKeditor version 4.10.1. `CustomConfig.js` is a Custom javascript file you can create it in your project. in CustomConfig.js add this codes:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {   
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;image:Link;link:advanced;link:upload';   
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/Home/UploadImage' //Action for Uploding image  
};
```

finally in Action use this codes:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadImage(IFormFile upload, string CKEditorFuncNum, string CKEditor, string langCode)
        {                  
            if (upload.Length <= 0 ) return null;
            if (!upload.IsImage())
            {
                var NotImageMessage = "please choose a picture";
                dynamic NotImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'uploaded': 0, 'error': { 'message': \"" + NotImageMessage + "\"}}");
                return Json(NotImage);
            }

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName).ToLower();

            Image image = Image.FromStream(upload.OpenReadStream());
            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;
            if ((width > 750) || (height > 500))
            {
                var DimensionErrorMessage = "Custom Message for error"
                dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'uploaded': 0, 'error': { 'message': \"" + DimensionErrorMessage + "\"}}");
                return Json(stuff);
            }

            if (upload.Length > 500 * 1024)
            {
                var LengthErrorMessage = "Custom Message for error";
                dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'uploaded': 0, 'error': { 'message': \"" + LengthErrorMessage + "\"}}");
                return Json(stuff);                
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/CKEditorImages",
                fileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                upload.CopyTo(stream);

            }

            var url = $"{"/images/CKEditorImages/"}{fileName}";
            var successMessage = "image is uploaded successfully";
            dynamic success = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'uploaded': 1,'fileName': \"" + fileName + "\",'url': \"" + url + "\", 'error': { 'message': \"" + successMessage + "\"}}");
            return Json(success);
        }
```

`IsImage()` is an extesion method for checking image:

```
    public static class ImageValidator
    {
        public static bool IsImage(this IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
You can create an anonymous type to not to use the JsonConvert which is error-prone:

`var success = new { uploaded = 1, fileName, url, error = new { message = successMessage } };


return Json(success);`